# How would I fix this function to change month depending on the date?

Tags: javascript, function, date

I'm trying to create a function that creates a dynamic date range based on the date supplied in a string.

What I've done so far:

Capture date in the string I'm looking to change;

Check to see if that date is a Thursday (if so the range will need to account for the weekend)

What I need to do:

Find a way to get the second date in the range to account for the weekend;

Find a way to make sure that the second date takes into account the last day of the month.

Apologies for old syntax, GTM doesn't like anything using ES6 so I'm a little constrained on this project.

Note I am using DD/MM/YYYY

```js
var regex = /[\d\/\d\/\d]/g;
var text = document.querySelector('.shipmentLineTitle b');
var originalDate = text.innerText.match(regex, "");
if (originalDate.length > 10) {
    originalDate.pop();
    originalDate.join('');
}
var ogDateString = originalDate.join('');
var dayNumber = originalDate.splice(0, 2).join('');
var monthNumber = originalDate.splice(1, 2).join('');
var yearNumber = originalDate.splice(2, 4).join('');

// if originalDate is a thursday (5) dynamicString will need to be a Monday (1).

var date = new Date(yearNumber, monthNumber -1, dayNumber);
var dynamicDateString = "";

if (date.getDay == 5) {
    var newDate = new Date(date) + (86400000 * 3);

    var dd = newDate.getDate();
    var mm = newDate.getMonth() +1;
    var yy = newDate.getFullYear();

    dymamicDateString = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yy;
} else {
    var newDate = new Date(date) + 86400000;

    var dd = newDate.getDate();
    var mm = newDate.getMonth() +1;
    var yy = newDate.getFullYear();
    dynamicDateString = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yy;
}

var newContent = 'Delivery will be made between ' + ogDateString + ' - ' + dynamicDateString + '. An accurate delivery date will be provided after you place your order.';

text.innerText = newContent;
```

```html
<span class="shipmentLineTitle">Delivery details: <b>your delivery will arrive on 09/10/2020 (1 delivery)</b></span>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. What is input and expected output? Show more than one example - including border cases

Comment: In your else condition , you are not using your variable "newDate" variable at all.

Comment: @Vimal Patel, Quite right, I should've checked before I posted. I've been playing around trying to get the right outcome and didn't change it back. Thank you.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for that. I've updated the snippet to better reflect the scenario.

Ideally the output would contain the date in the snippet and then a second date (either the next day, or if the next day would be the weekend, the monday afterwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thursday is day 4

Here is a simpler script

```js
var textField = document.querySelector('.shipmentLineTitle b'),
  text = textField.innerText,
  originalDate = text.match(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/)[0].split("/"),
  dayNumber = +originalDate[0],
  monthNumber = +originalDate[1],
  yearNumber = +originalDate[2],
  date = new Date(yearNumber, monthNumber - 1, dayNumber, 15, 0, 0, 0),
  aDay = 86400000,
  newDate = new Date(date),
  day = date.getDay(),
  daysToAdd = 1; // Sunday to Wednesday

// if originalDate is a Thursday (4) or Saturday (6), dynamicString will need to be a Monday (1).

if (day === 4) daysToAdd = 4; // Thursday - delivery Monday
else if (day === 6) daysToAdd = 2; // Saturday

newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + daysToAdd);
var dd = newDate.getDate(),
  mm = newDate.getMonth() + 1,
  yy = newDate.getFullYear(),
  dynamicDateString = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yy,
  newContent = text + ' - ' + dynamicDateString + '</b>. An accurate delivery date will be provided after you place your order.';
textField.innerHTML = newContent;
```

```html
<span class="shipmentLineTitle">Delivery details: <b>your delivery will arrive on 08/10/2020 (1 delivery)</b></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this. I'm going to spend some time now playing with the code and exploring where I went wrong. You've been a massive help.

Comment: Ah, I also needed to add FOUR days to thursdays

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to user moment.js a very good date library to manipulate dates. It has lot of function to add/substract dates, hours, days etc.
There is https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days which servers exactly what you need

Comment: 1. Where is react here? It's Google Tag Manager if I am not mistaken 2. If OP cannot use ES6 they are better off using their own. 3. OP was close. 4. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: corrected my link, but I agree this may not be good option in GTM context.